# Emscripten compile C++ on macOS: error "No thread API"

Tags: c++, compilation, emscripten

I'm trying to compile a relatively simple C++ program using emscripten for use in javascript (wasm). When I compile with the following settings

```
emcc ./lttb.cpp \
  --bind \
  --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm \
  --optimize=3 \
  -v \
  -nostdlib \
  -Wl,--export-all \
  -Wl,--no-entry \
  -Wl,--allow-undefined \
  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \
  -o lttb.wasm
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from ./lttb.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/2.0.12/libexec/system/include/emscripten/bind.h:14:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/2.0.12/libexec/system/include/libcxx/stddef.h:39:
/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/2.0.12/libexec/system/include/libcxx/__config:1134:6: error: "No thread API"
#    error "No thread API"
```

More details [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/13318#issue-793815107)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing build args to following

```
rm lttb.wasm
emcc ./lttb.cpp \
  --bind \
  --optimize=3 \
  -Wl,--export-all \
  -Wl,--allow-undefined \
  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \
  --no-entry \
  -o lttb.wasm
```

I believe it was the `-nostdlib` that was causing this particular issue (note: original build args were for a `C` wasm I was making, thus the necessary reconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are creating thread within `lttb.cpp`

In that case you must add:
`-s USE_PTHREADS=1`

It is also recommended to define in advance number of threads, e.g.:
`-s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=7`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I forgot I had posted this (add the solution that worked for me here). In my case I wasn't even having access to PTHREADS without the stdlib